# Javascript: form processing

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a form I'm attempting to send via AJAX and I'm having trouble converting it to a JSON string.  When the form is submitted in the traditional method, the POST array is sorted into a 2D array, how it should be.  The problem I'm having is Javascript doesn't recognize the names as a 2D array.  Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Also, it's a dynamic form, so just imagine the user can add up to seven sections.

```
<form id="reg">
  //Week 1: rendered by php
  <input type="checkbox" value="sunday" name="week[0][]" />
  //Imagine everyday of the week listed
  <input type="checkbox" value="saturday" name="week[0][]" />

  //Week 2: this section would be rendered by javascript when the user pressed a button
  <input type="checkbox" value="sunday" name="week[1][]" />
  //Imagine everyday of the week listed
  <input type="checkbox" value="saturday" name="week[1][]" />
</form>

//PHP interpretation
Array(
  0=>Array(Sunday...Saturday),
  1=>Array(Sunday...Saturday)
)

//Javascript interpretation
0=>Sunday
...
6=>Saturday
7=>Sunday
...
13=>Saturday
```

So to clarify my question, is it possible/how would I have javascript interpret the form names as a 2D array?

```
//Javascript code
function parseForm(){
  var x;
  formContents = new Object();

  for(x = 0; x < reg.length; x++){
    formContents[reg[x].name] = reg[x].value;
  }

  //afterwards, send to another function to convert to json
}
```

Comment: If you want to convert the form to JSON, best you give an example of the JSON you expect to generate, e.g. `[{'Sunday':'checked','Monday':'unchecked',...'Saturday':'checked'},{'Sunday':'checked','Monday':'unchecked',...'Saturday':'checked'}]`.

Comment: Something along the lines of: (Only submit the values checked)
[{"0":{"sunday":"checked","monday"}},{"1":{"tuesday":"checked","wednesday":"checked"}}]

Comment: If they are only submitted if checked, then you only need the names of the checked days so `[['sunday','saturday'],['tuesday','wednesday']]` should suffice.

Comment: Ok. The problem I'm having is when I loop through the form.  Instead of each name being an array element, it's treated as its own element. So when I loop through it, I want to have: array(array(saturday, sunday),array(monday, thursday)) I'll put the code in the original post so you can easily read it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ ? dataType can be json. After, you use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/.

Here an example of how you could add more field :
* Use one field to store current week count (hidden field in the  tag)
* Append function add fields (jQuery click function below)

```
<script>
$('#add').click(function(){
    // setup variable 
    var count = $('input[name=week_count]').val();

    // debug
    alert('current count value is ' + count);

    // now append all 7 days
    // will work this with an array and a string
    var days = array('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'. 'saturday'. 'sunday');

    // add + 1 to the count
    var count = count + 1;
    // update the field
    $('input[name=week_count]').attr('value', count);

    var string = '';
    for(var i in days){
        string+= '<input type="checkbox" name="week[' + count + '][]" value="' + days[i] + '" />';
    }

    // append to the div id reg
    $('#reg').append(string);

    // done
});
<script>

<html>
    <input type="hidden" name="week_count" value="0" />
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But my problem is processing the form with JavaScript.  When I'm attempting to loop through the form, each checkbox is independent of each other and not apart of an array.  For example, in my original post, I have two weeks, week0 and week1.  I want to have one, 2D array, with each sub-array containing a week's information. Example: 
  formContents = new Object();
  formContents["week0"] = new Array();
  formContents["week1"] = new Array();
  formContents["week0].push("monday","tuesday");
  formContents["week1].push("wednesday","friday");

Comment: Currently, this is how JavaScript is interpreting the form's names:
week[0][] = "sunday"
week[0][] = "monday"
week[1][] = "wednesday"
week[1][] = "thursday"

Comment: This is how I want it to be:
array(week[0] = ("sunday", "monday"), week[1] = ("wednesday", "thursday"))

Comment: Why don't just rebuild the array then ? Take a foreach on week and rebuild it the way you want. Also you can rebuild the array before sending within the $().submit(function(){});

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  I didn't know JavaScript didn't interpret the names as an array like PHP does.

Comment: Ahhh... everything is explained now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Unlike PHP, JavaScript doesn't convert names into arrays, instead it takes it as a literal string. So name="week[]" doesn't create an array named week, but creates a string "week[]".  In order to process my form, I'm going to have to manually check the weeks.  Thanks everyone for the help.